# ComboBox in Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.RadDataGrid

Tags: xaml, combobox, telerik, microsoft-metro

Windows 8
Visual Studio 2012 Express

Simple XAML:

```
<telerik:RadDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <telerik:RadDataGrid.Columns>
        <telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Whatever">
            <telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox>
                        <ComboBoxItem>one</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>two</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>three</ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
        </telerik:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </telerik:RadDataGrid.Columns>
</telerik:RadDataGrid>
```

The binding source is there just to populate the grid with something. In the real app I do use it. 
The problem: whenever I select an item from the combobox it does not remain selected, the items appear(dropdown), selection works, but the combobox displays nothing. An out of the grid combobox works ok.
I am new at this and I am definetely missing something.

Comment: seems to be caused by some repainting/refreshing issue <-- if you select something else in the grid the selection appears, if some other element (e.g. the dropdown of the another combobox ) overlaps the respective combo it appears again <-- tried out InvalidateArrange, etc o the grid and on the combo and still without effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is due to the fact that the ComboBox does not update its VisualState right after the SelectionChanged event is raised, because there is an animation in between.

Best regards,
Ivaylo

Comment: Hmm, I am using the WinRT ComboBox provided my ms.

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo - I meant MS ComboBox